# How can I serialize a condition in Unity Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of different creatures in a game, each of these animals will be unlocked if a specific condition is reached, of course the simple solution is to use an `enum` to categorize the creatures, but I want to be able to set the conditions themselves in inspector.

**Manager.cs**:

```cs
public Creature[] creatures;

public void Start()
{
    foreach (var creature in creatures)
    {
        if (creature.condition()) creature.Unlock();
    }
}
```

For example, to unlock Ogre creature, your player maximum life must be above 120, and to unlock Bat, your character must be faster than 80 move speed. One solution that has come to my mind so far is to serialize `Func<bool>`, But it does not work and I can not change the condition from the inspector. What is the best solution to this problem? Every suggestion is appreciated.

```cs
[SerializeField]
public Func<bool> condition = () => (player.maxHealth > 120);
```

Comment: Rather than saving a whole lot of conditions that the `Manager` has to worry about, have the manager contain a reference to a single `MonsterCapabilities` that returns flags (e.g. `IsBatAvailable`) or `struct` (with multiple flags) depending upon characteristics of the game at that point in time.   I don't think there is need to save the conditions that way unless conditions are truly dynamic in which case I'd recommend some form of workflow/orchestration.

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for your guidance, I'm really eager to better understand the terms you used and I searched for it.

Comment: _"Thanks for your guidance, I'm really **eager to** better **understand** the terms you used and **I searched for it**"_ - sorry I didn't mean to do that to you but well done in any event! :)  Now I don't think you need it here but just in case or maybe you have a need for it elsewhere, when I say workflow/orchestration I mean something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow).  Or even the groovy [Visual Scripting](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/about-unity-visual-scripting?uv=2021.1&projectId=604a0d68edbc2a080cd78d78#604a1ebdedbc2a03f83ce9c8) in Unity